# No Event fire after adding text in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, html.textboxfor

After i use the following code line:

```
this.txt_welcome_message.Text += "<a href='test' target='_blank'>";
```

The complete webpage does not fire any event. I tried it with:

```
CausesValidation="false"
```

it doesn't help. Here is one of the asp:buttons:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_special_details_for_welcome_message" Text="Weiter" CssClass="button" OnClick="btn_special_details_for_welcome_message_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
```

Before I add the text to the asp:TextBox all events firing accordingly, but afterwards no events firing.

Answer (score 0):

Hello your code work on a simple page.

Try to add UseSubmitBehavior="false" on Button propety. I have the same issue not a long and this work for me.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't help. My Button looks now:
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_special_details_for_welcome_message" Text="Weiter" CssClass="button"                                              OnClick="btn_special_details_for_welcome_message_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />